# How to map columns in Custom model to Identity model in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am implementing ASP.NET Core Identity in an existing project with an existing Database.

I have specified the Entities to use for `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` like this:

```
public partial class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser, MyRole, int>
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>(options =>
        {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>();
```

I was able to apply the migrations successfully to the database. But, on inspecting the AspNetRole table, I could see that EF created some extra columns.

[image]

How do I tell EF Core to use the existing colums (like `RoleId` for `Id` in the above image) instead of creating new ones?

Also, I noticed that EF Core changed `MyRoles` table name to `AspNetRoles` which was not the case with the `MyUsers` table. `MyUsers` table name remained the same even though extra columns were created as I mentioned above. Why is that?

PS: I am using DotNet Core 3.0 with EF Core 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `[Column()]` annotations to change the default column name:

   ```cs
   public class MyRole: IdentityRole<int>
   {
       [Column("RoleId")]
       public override int Id { get; set; }

       [Column("RoleName")]
       public override string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. To reuse the old table `MyRoles`, custom the `OnModelCreating(builder)` method:

   ```
   public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser, MyRole, int>
   {
       ...

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           builder.Entity<MyRole>(e =>{
               e.ToTable("MyRoles");
           });
       }
   }
   ```